# Discord Token joiner with discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

How do I make a discord.py command where when you do: !join "THE_TOKEN_HERE".
It will join a server that is in the code.

Comment: Bots cannot join a server unless a member from the server with permissions invites the bot and manually grants all the permissions for the bot.

Answer (score 3):

**You can't**, as bots require certain permissions and can create a lot of unwanted spam in a server, bots have to be invited manually by someone. This would also allow bots to join lots of guilds at random by just generating random invite links and hoping some would be valid.

If you don't have permission to invite a bot to the server, you also shouldn't be able to do so by giving it an invite link. That would be ridiculous. If you *do* have permissions, you can invite it manually.